# filesize() return 0 while trying to fread() a json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, fopen, filesize

Details about my Goal :

> I Wanted to combine a new Data comes from my mobile application with the data which is stored on a Json file and used that data to process user things but any data greater than 1KB starts the error .

Error Codes : `PHP Warning:  fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0`

**I've make sure the file size is not 0, its 4.89KB !**

**The Code :**

```
        $RawFile = fopen($FileName, "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
         $IsiFile = fread($RawFile,filesize($FileName));
          $DataFile = json_decode($IsiFile, true);
           $DataPengguna = $DataFile[$UserID];
           $DataOverwrite = $DataPengguna . '' . $tulisan;
          $DataFile[$UserID] = $DataOverwrite;
         fwrite($RawFile, json_encode($DataFile));
        fclose($RawFile);
```

The contents of Json file : [Prnt.sc/r9hek8](https://prnt.sc/r9hek8)

Mean of the Variable in my code :

> $IsiFile = The Json
>
> $DataFile = I prefer Array to access the data
>
> $DataPengguna = The user Data [Every user have their own UserID]
>
> $DataOverwrite = Combine the old already stored data with the new data
>
> Put it back on the array and do fwrite(),  then closed the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filesize() always reads 0 bytes even though file size isn't 0 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225750/filesize-always-reads-0-bytes-even-though-file-size-isnt-0-bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place of a logical error: `fopen($FileName, "w+")`
The "w+" mode always drops a file content. Just use "r+" mode and if you need write to file later, reopen it with "w+" mode.

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly! I forgot that the w+ mode will delete the file contents 